# More general help, I believe I'm suppose to use "map(lambda....)" -

Tags: python, string, lambda

```
# check if string is panagram (phrase which contains every letter of the
# alphabet)

def panagram_check(str0, alphabet=string.ascii.lowercase):

        alltrues = [True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,
                    True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,
                    True,True,True,True,True]

        # so let's build this list...

        list_of_bools = []

        for achar in alphabet:

            for bchar in str0:
                if achar != bchar:
                    zerocheck = False

                else:  zerocheck = True

            list_of_bools = list_of_bools+zerocheck

        return (list_of_bools==alltrues)
```

This returns error "name string is not defined" which also confuses me
but if lambda expressions help this be not ugly, any clues?

Comment: did you `import string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if every letter from the alphabet ([ascii_lowercase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase)) is in the phrase using [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
import string


def panagram_check(phrase, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    uniques_letters_in_phrase = set(phrase.lower())
    return all(letter in uniques_letters_in_phrase for letter in alphabet)


print(panagram_check("Two driven jocks help fax my big quiz.​"))
print(panagram_check("Not a panagram"))
```

**Output**

```
True
False
```

The statement: `uniques_letters_in_phrase = set(phrase.lower())` converts the phrase to a set, with the purpose of speeding the containability check. Note that you must import string to have access to `ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def panagram_check(str0, alphabet=string.ascii.lowercase):
    return set(str0.lower()) & set(alphabet) == set(alphabet)
```